# How can I manipulate the multicore in solr dynamically

Tags: solr, solrj

I am new to apache solr.
I want to manipulate the multicore dynamically using CoreAdminHandler class of
 `org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler;`

There are no tutorials on how to use it nor any good example I could google out.
Please give me some example of how can I manipulate multicore which are deployed in tomcat(not embedded) using CoreAdminHandler and solrj.

How can I specify the path of my tomcat server where solr is deployed for CoreAdminHandler/coreContainer. 
And how to specify the path where multicores are placed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10043721/1356127 This post gave me some idea of creating server then using it for CoreAdmin Request and Responses  I am still searching for link where I can see more about CoreAdminHandler activities like using CREATE, SWAP, LOAD etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example you can use to get the list of the available cores through a status request:

```
CoreAdminRequest adminRequest = new CoreAdminRequest();
adminRequest.setAction(CoreAdminAction.STATUS);
CoreAdminResponse adminResponse = adminRequest.process(new CommonsHttpSolrServer(solrUrl));
NamedList<NamedList<Object>> coreStatus = adminResponse.getCoreStatus();
```

The following are the available `CoreAdmin` actions you can use:

```
STATUS,  
LOAD,
UNLOAD,
RELOAD,
CREATE,
PERSIST,
SWAP,
RENAME,
@Deprecated
ALIAS,
MERGEINDEXES;
```

The code you can use is pretty much the same, you just have to pick the right action and correctly read the results within the returned `NamedList` object. Let me know if you have some more specific question.

Comment: Thank you @javanna. That works...Ok I'll ask the other question with new thread and will provide link here so that you can help me

Comment: here is a new thread where you can help me about solr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716690/which-jars-are-needed-to-use-concurrentupdatesolrserver