# Which jars are needed to use ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer?

Tags: apache, solr, solrj

Currently using

```
solrServer = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(serverUrl);
```

and with these jars..

```
apache-solr-core-3.6.0
apache-solr-solrj-3.6.0
commons-codec-1.6
commons-httpclient-3.1
commons-io-2.1
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1
slf4j-api-1.6.1
slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1
lucene-core-3.5.0
```

However apache solr deprecated `CommonHttpSolrServer` and suggested `ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer`
Replacing `CommonHttpSolrServer` by `ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer` gives runtime exception ..

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor

which needs the jar `httpcore-4.0-alpha6.jar`

 Exception also indicate three more exceptions. 
 
Anybody having list of which extra jars like `httpcore-4.0-alpha6.jar` are needed to replace `CommonHttpSolrServer` by `ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3374
You need to include `httpcore`, `httpmime` and `httpclient` jars.

Also, I noticed that you are using Solr 3.6 jars with Lucene 3.5 jars - it is generally a good idea to keep Solr and Lucene jar versions in sync.

Comment: Thank you @nikhil500. I added those jars (httpcore, httpmime, httpclient) However I am still getting class not found exception.    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/SyncBasicHttpParams

Comment: using httpcore-4.0-alpha6.jar gave such exception now updated to httpcore-4.2.jar