# solrj reload request

Tags: reload, solrj

Can you please help me with this:

How can I reload the updated schema.xml using SolrJ?

[Here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD) is the link that says it is possible. But how to send this request?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10698335/633239). This should be the code you're looking for:

```
CoreAdminRequest adminRequest = new CoreAdminRequest();
adminRequest.setAction(CoreAdminAction.RELOAD);
CoreAdminResponse adminResponse = adminRequest.process(new CommonsHttpSolrServer(solrUrl));
NamedList<NamedList<Object>> coreStatus = adminResponse.getCoreStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.reload(String coreName)
```

where `coreName` is the name of the SolrCore to reload.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer: the code you mentioned is server side, while the question is about doing it from client side through solrj.