# Cannot post to a core in solr using SimplePostTool

Tags: solr

I am new to using solr. I currently have solr running on `http://localhost::8983/solr`.
My goal is to index numerous files. I have verified that the core I'm trying to post to exists by listing all cores in solr,I used the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668534/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-cores-in-a-solr-server-using-solrj)

I also understand that to post to a specific core using SimplePostTool, one must use `java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/<corename>/update -jar post.jar <filename>`

The issue, however, is that I get the following error.

```
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file tmpzWztTN
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 Not Found
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update..
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 Not Found for url http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true
Time spent: 0:00:00.023
```

Since I have verified that the core, `collection1`, exists, why does it say the url cannot be found? What am i missing? How does one fix this?

Comment: In the `solrconfig.xml` pf that core, does a `<requestHandler name="/update" ... />` exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in @cheffe's comment, it turns out I was missing `<requestHandler> name="/update" ...`

I am a solr noob so I looked up `requestHandlers`'s  [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler#Implementing_a_Request_Handler). This [tutorial](http://kevindoran1.blogspot.com/2013/02/solr-tutorial.html) was also helpful. In essense, I only added the following line in my `solrconfig.xml` file

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
```

Answer (score 15):

It looks like `gettingstarted` core is not being created. 
Create 'gettingstarted' core with this command.

```
bin/solr create -c gettingstarted
```

Once the core is created `bin/post -c gettingstarted docs/` command runs without any error.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmation,  this actually worked for me [Win10, solr 5.4.1, java 1.8.0_60]:

```
$ java -Dauto -Dc=gettingstarted -Drecursive -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar  docs/quickstart.html
```

resulted into … HTTP ERROR 404 url … as above, I did as recommended:

```
$ .\bin\solr create -c gettingstarted
```

& then

```
$ java -Dauto -Dc=gettingstarted -Drecursive -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar  .\docs
```

worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me while running the solr start tutorial. I was missing creating the collection. After running "$ .\bin\solr create -c gettingstarted", I could run "$ java -Dc=gettingstarted -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar example/exampledocs/*.xml" just fine

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was I was using a port other than 8983. I had to include the correct port in my post command.

```
bin/post -p 1234 -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/*.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

In solr-5.4.1 I couldn't post to my core either and got this message:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/gettingstarted/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update?commit=true
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/gettingstarted/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
Time spent: 0:00:00.030
```

I fixed the problem adding the following line to
`~/solr-5.4.1/server/solr/corex/solrconfig.xml:`

(I added it immediately after the `RequestHandlers` section header)

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
```

Then I used (I use a new core name):

```
$ bin/post -c <core_name> example/exampledocs/money.xml
```

It worked perfectly. Note that you have to provide the whole path for the `.xml` file (or any file you wish to upload to solr.)

Answer (score 0):

First Create a core :

**solr-7.6.0\bin>solr create -c vjcore**

then you can see :

Created new core 'vjcore2'

Then navigate to this directory :

**solr-7.6.0\example\exampledocs>**

**java -jar -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/vjcore2/update post.jar ipod_other.xml**

then go the browser hit this : http://localhost:8983/solr/#/vjcore

your core is created which will contains 2 documents

Hope this will help !

Thanks
-Vj