# Running a weekly update on a live Solr environment

Tags: solr, live, environment

I have a server which has a Solr Environment hosted on it. I want to run a weekly update of the data that our Solr database contains.

I have a couple solutions but I was wondering whether one is possible and if it is which one would be better:

My first solution is to have 2 Servers with a Solr environment on both and when one is updating you just switch the url using to connect to Solr and connect to the other one.

My other solution is the one I am not sure how to do. Is there a way to switch the datasource that a Solr environment looks at without restarting it or cutting out any current searches.

If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use SolrCloud and let it do the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the size of the data, you can probably just keep the Solr core running while doing the update. First issue a delete, then index the data and finally commit the changes. The new index state won't be seen before the commit is issued, which allows you to serve the old data while waiting for the indexing to complete.

Another option is to use the core admin to switch cores as you mentioned, similar to [copying data into other cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492804/solr-copy-data-from-crawler-core-into-search-core/25502067#25502067) (drop the mergeindex command).

If you're also talking about updating and upgrading the actual Solr version or application server while still serving content, having a second server that replicates the index from the master is an easy way to get more redundancy. That way you can keep serving queries from the second server while the first one is being maintained and then do it the other way around. Point your clients to an HTTP load balancer, and take the maintained server out of the list of servers serving requests while it's down. This will also make you resistant against single hardware failures, etc.

There's also the option of setting up SolrCloud, but that might require a bit more restructuring.