# Retrieve schema info from HttpSolrServer and CloudSolrServer with SolrJ

Tags: solr, solrj

[HttpSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.html)/[CloudSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrServer.html) support the `/schema` request handler but that isn't supported on the [EmbeddedSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer.html) and I would like a way to access the same information using SolrJ (and without HTTP requests).

When using EmbeddedSolrServer, the instance is created by passing a [CoreContainer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-core/index.html?org/apache/solr/core/CoreContainer.html) to the constructor. Later, the CoreContainer can be queried for all (well, just the one in the case of an embedded server) [SolrCore](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/core/SolrCore.html)s with the `getCores()` method. From any given SolrCore I can obtain its schema using `getSchema()`.

I now want to do the same thing but with an HttpSolrServer server and a CloudSolrServer. They, however, don't seem to have a way to ask for the list of loaded SolrCores or CoreContainers or anything. I know about the [CoreAdmin](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) but that only retrieves the status of each core, with no way to get Java instances of `SolrCore`.

Is it possible to obtain a list of SolrCores from a HttpSolrServer/CloudSolrServer using SolrJ, and how is it done?

Comment: Why do you need that information?

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668534/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-cores-in-a-solr-server-using-solrj

Comment: I agree with @abhishekbafna give us a bit of background what you want to achieve, probably there is another way.

Comment: Question updated. The schema is already published via the `/schema` resource handler, just not for embedded servers which don't support that resource handler. So `/schema` works for some but not all cases, and `getCores()` works for the exact complement of cases. I am looking for something that will work for all three types of SolrServer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Solr 5.3 SolrJ has API for Schema Access - see [SchemaRequest](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/schema/SchemaRequest.html).

For example, to retrieve collection schema one can use (in Solr 7) :

```
CloudSolrClient client = ...;
SchemaRequest request = new SchemaRequest();
SchemaResponse response = request.process(client, "collectionName");
SchemaRepresentation schema = response.getSchemaRepresentation();
```